# Declaring special (infix) functions in R packages

Tags: r, package, infix-notation

I am writing a package containing a function such as:

```
"%IN%" <- function(x, table) x & match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

When I `Build & Reload` the package (I use RStudio), this function is not available, as opposed to all other functions defined in the package.

How do I make this work?

Comment: No, I was unaware of it until now

Comment: Ha! That was the catch. The regex in the NAMESPACE file did not account for this special name. Now the next challenge will be to appropriately document it. New question maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution entails installing `roxygen2` and modifying the `NAMESPACE` file to include a line such as:

```
export("%IN%")
```