# Documenting special (infix) functions in R packages

Tags: r, documentation, package, infix-notation

In an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660864/declaring-special-infix-functions-in-r-packages), I asked about declaring such functions in R packages and making them work. Having succeeded, I'm now trying to document one such function.

I created an `Rd` file with the function's name as a title, but when running the `CHECK`, I get the following warning:

```
* checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented code objects:
  '%IN%'
```

I tried several names such as `%IN%.Rd` or `'%IN%'.Rd`, to no avail. Any hints on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goto guide would definitely be section 2.1.1 "Documenting functions"[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions) of the "Writing R Extensions" manual. As @joran pointed out in a comment the important part maybe the use of an `\alias`.  According to the "Writing R extensions" manual the `%`s need to be escaped at least in `\alias` and in the text. About `\name` it states: " [name should not contain] ‘!’ ‘|’ nor ‘@’, and to avoid possible problems with the HTML help system it should not contain ‘/’ nor a space. (LaTeX special characters are allowed, but may not be collated correctly in the index.)"[<sup>[2]</sup>](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions) and about `\alias`: " Percent and left brace need to be escaped by a backslash."[<sup>[3]</sup>](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions)

Comment: The important part here is the use of an `\alias`, I think. Although the `%`'s do need to be escaped in the text of the documentation themselves as well.

Comment: True, @joran. `\name{\%IN\%}` and `\alias{\%IN\%}` should work.

Comment: I was able to make it work with `\alias{\%IN\%}` and the file renamed to `IN.Rd`. The `\name` only impacts the heading of the help page and will not generate any error, either way.

Comment: I've read section 2.1.1 "Documenting functions" in the `R` manual again. About `name` it states: " [name should not contain] ‘!’ ‘|’ nor ‘@’, and to avoid possible problems with the HTML help system it should not contain ‘/’ nor a space. (LaTeX special characters are allowed, but may not be collated correctly in the index.)" and about `alias`: " Percent and left brace need to be escaped by a backslash." (2014-07-16T06:34+02:00)